# Computer Modern TTF and TFM files with original 7-bit codepoints

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, java, font-metrics

## Background

While modernizing the [New Typesetting System](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/nts) (NTS) into a 100% pure Java library to generate SVG versions of TeX, I've hit an impasse.

## Problem

The issue is that math and ligatures don't render correctly. David Carlisle told me:

> there are two issues, the font format and the encoding, classic tex really doesn't care about the format, as long as it has the tfm metrics the real font could be pk (bitmap) pfa or pfb (type1) ttf (truetype) or whatever you need, but the font has to be in the legacy encoding with all characters below 127. to use latinmodern-math.otf the main issue is not that it is opentype format, but that it is unicode encoded so you need to redefine \sqrt (and a couple of thousand other commands) to access position 8730, unicode slot for √

That tracks. When the code point for `\pi` comes in, the Java code receives 0x19 (25 decimal). Very few TTF/OTF fonts map codepoint 25 to a π glyph, thus the roadblock.

## Code

I've extended Knuth's unmodified `plain.tex` to use [Belleek](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/belleek) by creating `ext/math.tex`, which basically contains the following:

```tex
% Change fonts to use Latin Modern.
\input base/plain

\font\tensy=blsy
\font\tenex=blex
\font\teni=rblmi
\textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
\textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex
```

This allows writing `document.tex` as follows:

```tex
\input ext/math

$\sqrt{\pi}$

\bye
```

The system  `.tfm` files are fudged by borrowing the TFM files from [txfonts/tfm](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/txfonts/tfm), which produces:

[image: math]

FWIW, the txfonts were copied over as the Belleek TFMs as follows:

- txfonts/tfm/txex.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/blex.tfm
- txfonts/tfm/txsy.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/blsy.tfm
- txfonts/tfm/rtxmi.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/rblmi.tfm

For fun, I rendered the following, as well:

```tex
\input ext/math

$-\frac{{\hbar ^2 }}{{2m}}\frac{{\partial ^2 \psi (x,t)}}{{\partial x^2 }} + U(x)\psi (x,t) = i\hbar \frac{{\partial\psi (x,t)}}{{\partial t}}$

\par
  $E=mc^2$
\par
  $\sqrt{\pi}$
\par
  $(a+b)^2=a^2 + 2ab + b^2$
\par
  $S_x = sqrt((SS_x)/(N-1))$
\par
  $e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0$
\par
  $\sigma=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i(x_i-\mu)^2}$
\par
  $\sqrt[n]{\pi}$
\par
  $\sqrt[n]{|z| . e^{i \theta}} = \sqrt[n]{|z| . e^{i (\frac{\theta + 2 k \pi}{n})}}, k \in \lbrace 0, ..., n-1 \rbrace, n \in NN$
\par
  $\vec{u}^2 \tilde{\nu}$
\par
  $\sum_{i=1}^n i = (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i) + n =\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
\par
  $\int_{a}^{b} x^2 dx$
\par
  $G_{\mu \nu} = \frac{8 \pi G}{c^4} T_{{\mu \nu}}$
\par
  $\prod_{i=a}^{b} f(i)$
\par
  $u(n) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1-e^{-jw}} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \pi \delta (\omega + 2\pi k)$
\par
  $\rightleftharpoons\angle\hbar$

\bye
```

That produced:

[image: math-2]

Using the original [Computer Modern TFM](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/tfm) files produces similar results. That is:

- cm/tfm/cmmi10.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/rblmi.tfm
- cm/tfm/cmex10.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/blex.tfm
- cm/tfm/cmsy10.tfm ➡ belleek/tfm/blsy.tfm

## Questions

What do I need to do to typeset math correctly in Java? Some ideas:

- Try to create a TFM file for Belleek's TTF files.
- Add [Java code](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/nts/blob/f96d21c21742e6e269c6057f3b2d6c8509646927/src/main/java/nts/svg/Turtle.java#L103) to map Knuth's codepoints from Computer Modern Math into Latin Modern Math, such as by reading a CSV file of the form:

  ```
  cmr10,0x11,rm-lmr10,0xFB00
  cmmi10,0x19,latinmodern-math,0x03C0
  ```
- If adding Java code, how would I create the map?
- Try to recreate Computer Modern from Knuth's original `.mf` files, similar to how Richard Kinch created Belleek, and create the `.tfm` files as well.
- Beg Richard Kinch for Belleek's TFM files.

I'm definitely open to other ideas, short of integrating XeTeX/LuaTeX/MathJax/KaTeX, or switching to [JLaTeXMath](https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath/).

Comment: Fortunately, the mapping of LaTeX commands to Unicode codepoints [has already been done.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) In my opinion, you will get much better results for less effort by using that mapping on an OpenType math font than by trying to reimplement seven-bit font encodings from the 1970s in a file format from the 1990s.

Comment: NTS is [hard-coded](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/nts/blob/d0d00e10402840acf32016c0514187ce6dbc7198/src/main/java/nts/tex/KtPrimitives.java#L1057) to 7-bit ASCII. Good to know about `unicode-math-table.tex`, thanks! If you have suggestions for how to integrate it, do tell. A PR would be amazing.

Comment: Just a note: AFAIK about 20 years ago Gerd Neugebauer from DANTE already made a new Jave implementation of TeX, that is able to work with TTF and OTF. [The source is available from githgub.](https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/extex). I've never tried to use it, only heard about. However, it seems there is already a [SVGDocumentWriter](https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/extex/blob/master/ExTeX/src/java/de/dante/extex/backend/documentWriter/svg/SVGDocumentWriter.java).

Comment: Thanks, @cabohah. I had forked that version years ago and found it too complex for my needs. Also, its SVGDocumentWriter looks sluggish (compared with [mine](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/KeenType/blob/fef005579021f394b6954073481e0e2e6651cda6/svg/src/main/java/com/whitemagicsoftware/keentype/svg/KtSvgFormatWriter.java#L24), but can't say for sure without benchmarking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaKoMa's TTF files have codepoints that are similar to the  codepoints found in Belleek's TTF files (and thus Knuth's original codepoints), with separate groups of glyphs shifted up. The shifts, in decimal, are:

- 0 to 9 are shifted to 161 to 170
- 20 is shifted to 128
- 10 to 32 are shifted to 173 to 195

The codeshifts are applied consistently across all the `cm*.ttf` files. This allows the code shifts to be captured using a single Java conversion function, such as:

```java
  private static final Function<Integer, Integer> CM = codepoint -> {
    if( codepoint <= 9 ) {
      // 0 to 9 are shifted to 161 to 170
      return codepoint + 161;
    }
    else if( codepoint == 20 ) {
      // 20 is shifted to 128
      return 128;
    }
    else if( codepoint <= 32 ) {
      // 10 to 32 are shifted to 173 to 195
      return codepoint + 163;
    }

    return codepoint;
  };
```

NTS can now produce the following scalable vector graphic:

[image: Math]

There are a few outstanding issues, but for a quick preview before typesetting using ConTeXt (or any other TeX-based system), it looks decent.